# How do I set the color of a break line in microsoft word?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

Whenever you type === or something alike in Microsoft word and click enter, it inserts a breakline, I would like to know the way to change the color of it, since i don't really feel like inserting lines and reorganizing them every time I make changes in the document

[image]

I'd like to know if there is a way to change that breakline said color, tried changing colors and messing around with the menus but couldn't find the option.

Answer (score 4):

To change the color of the break line in Microsoft Word:

1. Place the curser immediately above the horizontal break line.
2. In the Home tab > Paragraph group, click the arrow next to the
   Borders icon. This opens a menu.
3. From the menu, select Borders and Shading.
4. Select a color.
5. Again, from the menu, select Bottom Border.

The color of the break line will now be the color that you have chosen.